# Flipper com texto no Android (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um app no Android Studio e gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de fazer um back e forward deslizando o dedo (Flipper eu acho) chamando o próximo texto. Até o momento já tenho botões fazendo a função, gostaria de substituir os botões pelo flipper.

Comment: Veja na documentação [Using ViewPager for Screen Slides](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Acho que o termo mais usado é `swipe` significando deslizar. `Flip` é usado para definir o efeito de girar no proprio eixo. Você pode até combinar os dois de forma que ao deslizar o dedo a transição `flipa` as telas.